# Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. If $A$ is invertible, then $|A| \neq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, functions, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. If $A$ is invertible, then $|A| \neq 0$.

How I can justifying the answer?

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is invertible, then there exists a matrix $B$ with $AB=I$, the identity. Then $\det(A)\cdot\det(B)=\det(AB)=\det(I)=1$, so $\det(A)\ne 0$.